# Segfault in simple program: open, close file in assembly, x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

So I have file `file1` in the same directory as the program. I compile it with

```
nasm -f elf64 -o prog.o prog.asm
ld --fatal-warnings -o prog prog.o
```

and run with `./prog file1`, but it gives me SegFault

```
global _start

exit_error:
  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, 1
  syscall

exit_ok:
  mov rax, 60
  syscall

_start:
  cmp qword [rsp], 2
  jne exit_error
  mov rdi, [rsp + 16]

  call open_file

  call close_file

  mov rdi, 0
  jmp exit_ok

open_file:
  mov rax, 2
  mov rsi, 0
  syscall
  mov rdi, [rax]
  ret

close_file:
  mov rax, 0
  syscall
  ret
```

I also tried running it with: `strace ./prog file1` and I get:

```
execve("./prog", ["./prog", "file1"], 0x7ffc8edac5e8 /* 63 vars */) = 0
open("file1", O_RDONLY)                 = 3
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x3} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can someone explain me why t doesn't work?

Comment: Use a debugger. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help. The fault is at `mov rdi, [rax]` but we can't tell what you wanted that to do. `rax` is a file descriptor at that point, likely `3` and that's not a valid pointer. Maybe you just wanted `mov rdi, rax` to return it in `rdi`?

Comment: A segfault only happens when you dereference memory; this happens at three points in your program, and only once after the `open` syscall has been used. If you use a debugger and stop at `mov rdi, [rax]`, you will find that `rax` probably contains something like 3, not a pinter.